# getting string from byte array in different OS with Java

Tags: java, linux, string, arrays

I'm trying to convert a byte array in string with simple code:

```
System.out.printf("%s \n", new String(b));
```

where `b` has this content (in hex chars):

> 32d001000001000000000000246d3639653331697769736374683134633439687763796c7862796f74697167786f786c7504696e666f0000010001

If I run my code in Windows I get the entire decoded `String`, however in Linux it seems dropped until the null byte (00). If I skip these bytes the correct `String` in produced.

How can I get the same result in Linux OS?
Sorry but I can't attach image due to restriction :'(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and you are sure that the input in windows and linux is identical? Java is not platform dependent, if you provide the same input, it should give the same output

Comment: @Stultuske: That's not true. The constructor the OP is using uses the platform-default encoding. Just because Java can run on multiple platforms doesn't mean that every possible program gives the same result on every platform. There are plenty of platform-specific parts, e.g. file separators, path separators and line breaks.

Comment: @Stultuske: the input is the same, I've tried to specify charset into the String ctor, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's because you're using the constructor that uses the *platform default encoding* to convert binary data to text. It's entirely reasonable for it to create different strings on different platforms - although I suspect your interpretation of Linux "dropping until the null byte" is incorrect, and may be due to the way you're displaying the strings.

Don't use the platform default encoding - or do so explicitly if you *really* want it. Assuming this really *is* text data, specify an appropriate encoding e.g. using `StandardCharsets`.

However, if this is arbitrary binary data (e.g. the result of encryption or compression) then you shouldn't be converting it into a string in this way at all - you should use a hex or base64 conversion.

Comment: input contains mixed data, text and others. In window I can show all printable chars into the eclipse console, not in Linux.

Comment: @DomenicoChiarito: Well the first thing you need to do is work out which parts of the input are meant to be text. Next you should understand that you need to know which encoding the text is in... Basically there isn't nearly enough information for us to give specific help at the moment. You could decide to treat the whole thing as ISO-8859-1, but that's unlikely to give you a useful result...

Comment: UTF8 is fine as charset, then I found it was just a question of console, it doesn't show me the output string but the variable contains all chars, printable and not. tks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert Byte array into String format correctly, we have to explicitly create a String object and assign the Byte array to it.

```
String s = new String(bytes);
```

reference:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/

Comment: yes, but this give me a different result in different OS with the same input

Answer (score 0):

Choose the right charset :

String s = new String(bytes, "UTF-16");

or

String s = new String(bytes, "EUC-JP");

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html